# logout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_page'

Tags: python-3.7, django-1.11, django-2.2

Are there no next_page or template_name arguments in Django 2.2 for logout and login? I got these errors when upgraded from Django 1.11 to Django 2.2!!

This is my urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

url(r'^logout/$',logout, {'next_page': '/'},name='logout'),
```

The logout_url from settings.py is

```
LOGOUT_URL = '/'
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError at /portal/logout/
logout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_page'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
logout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next_page'
```

The same thing happened with login too

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from landing.views import landing_validation

app_name='landing'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', landing_validation, name='landing')
]
```

views.py

```
def landing_validation(request):
  login_response = login(request, template_name='landing.html')

  return login_response

TypeError at /
login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'
```

Comment: There are a lot of changes from 1.11; especially with the way urls are served. I'd start here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/ This site had good info too:
https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/ Hope this helps.

Comment: How's it going? Did you find a solution? :D

Answer (score 6):

If you're still wondering about a solution for that issue after migrating, here is the simplest one:

In `settings.py` add:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

`home` refers to your home page route `name` or just

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'  # Or maybe another URL you want to set.
```

and then in your `urls.py` change your route to be like this:

```
url(r'^logout$', LogoutView.as_view(),  name='logout'),
```

`LogoutView` comes is imported `from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView`